# Simple JavaScript Map - Using an Object as the Return

Tags: javascript, iteration, map-function

I'm studying the `map` function and tried to make a contrived example which I thought would work. This code works fine:

```
let students = [{name: 'Susan', grades: [88, 38, 28]}, {name: 'Robert', grades: [28,97, 17]}];
let newStudents = students.map((el) => el.name);  
console.log(newStudents); // [ 'Susan', 'Robert' ]
```

But what I really wanted was the following in the `map` function:

```
let newStudents = students.map((el) => {name: el.name});
// [ undefined, undefined ]
// I assumed to get back the following: [ {name: 'Susan'}, {name: 'Robert'} ]
```

Why is using an object in the return portion of the `map` function not allowed?

Comment: Try this `let newStudents = students.map((el) => {return {name: el.name}});`

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap the object in normal function parenthesis.

```
let newStudents = students.map((el) => ({name: el.name}));
                                        ^              ^
```

```js
let students = [{name: 'Susan', grades: [88, 38, 28]}, {name: 'Robert', grades: [28,97, 17]}];
let newStudents = students.map((el) => ({name: el.name}));
console.log(newStudents);
```

Comment: Ah ok thank you. And why exactly do I need the extra parenthesis?

Comment: It causes an explicit return. Without them or `return` the curly brakets denote a function block.